# An exception occurred while executing query, column not found in Symfony 2.3

Tags: symfony, command-line, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

While executing command through command line I'm getting this error "column not found"

```
    [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                                                                                
  An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.first_name AS first_name2, t0.last_name AS last_name3, t0.email AS email4, t  
  0.gender AS gender5, t0.is_active AS is_active6, t0.vote_count AS vote_count7, t0.created_at AS created_at8, t0.updated_at AS updated_at9,   
  t0.fbUserId AS fbUserId10, t0.username AS username11, t0.password AS password12, t0.salt AS salt13 FROM users t0 WHERE t0.is_active = ?' wi  
  th params [0]:                                                                                                                               
  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.fbUserId' in 'field list'                                                         

  [PDOException]                                                                        
  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.fbUserId' in 'field list'
```

Any idea why only through command line I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably You have forgotten to update your schema , If it is please update your schema ..

Answer (score 1):

For version Symfony > 2.7 use:

> php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

For version Symfony < 2.7 use:

> php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Comment: In your answer please include some explanation as to why this might help the op

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurred since you have not updated your database schema according to your model. Use following command to update the schema:

```
         php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

or use following command for upper versions (> 2.8)

```
         php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```